# Im doing project on QuickBlox Chat Application, having some doubts

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener, quickblox

When i click send button it is not sending any messages
The program gives no error, please help me solve this.

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
            chatMessage.setBody(edtContent.getText().toString());
            chatMessage.setSenderId(QBChatService.getInstance().getUser().getId());
            chatMessage.setSaveToHistory(true);


            try {
                qbChatDialog.sendMessage(chatMessage);
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().putMessage(qbChatDialog.getDialogId(), chatMessage);
            ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages = QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().getChatMessagesByDialogId(qbChatDialog.getDialogId());
            adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getBaseContext(), messages);
            lstChatMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/77) on github, It also have an example

Comment: No solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the quick blox sdk in my app. below is the code for sending message and its working fine.

```
 private void sendChatMessage(String text) {
    QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
    chatMessage.setBody(text);
    chatMessage.setProperty(PROPERTY_SAVE_TO_HISTORY, "1");
    chatMessage.setDateSent(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    try {
        if (Network.isNetworkConnected(ChatActivity.this)) {
            chatDialog.sendMessage(chatMessage);
            showMessage(chatMessage);
            messageEditText.setText("");
            checkIfOpponentIsOnline(chatMessage.getBody());
        } else {
            ToastUtil.showShortToast(ChatActivity.this, "Please check Internet connection and Try again");
        }
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send a message", e);
        ToastUtil.showShortToast(ChatActivity.this, R.string.chat_send_message_error);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send a message", e);
    }
}
```

If you are still having trouble then you must check the dialogId and dialogUsers on your Quickblox console . There must be something wrong.Check for existence of users in dialog. Also check for ChatService Session cause if there is no session you won't be able to send any messages.